# PHP to android using HTTPpost

Tags: android

Is there a way to send the selected data from my website to an android application? I want to use the data selected to use on conditions in android.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "data selected"? This is completely unclear. Please clarify your question.

Comment: for example I have a combo box in my web. I will select the first option and I want to send this option selected to my android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use WebView to load the webpage, you can invoke a native-method by using the JavaScriptInterface.
For example:

Bind the JavascriptInterface to your WebView in Android:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
```

in HTML:

```
 <button onclick="appTest('test');return false;">test-button</button>
```

in Javascript:

```
function appTest(args) {
 if (typeof Android != "undefined"){ 
   if (Android.appTest!= "undefined") {
    Android.appTest(args);
   }
 }
}
```

and finally in Android:

```
class JavaScriptInterface {

  public void appTest(String s) {
     //do something
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, didn't see HTTPpost in the header

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will study your response to get oriented and able to use this to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Nope , It is not possible to send data using httppost from server to android.

### Approach 1:

For this kind of data transmission you need to implement socket programming both the side.
Like : XMPP Server(Openfire);

### Approac 2:

1) Implement push notification at device side.

2) Make one webservice at server side which will return response(whatever you want to send to mobile side).

3) Fire pushnotification from your server to google server and google server will send that push to android device.

4) When android receive push it will call the webservice of your server and will get the date that you want to send.

We are using Second approach in our application IjoomerAdvance.

**Refer this link for Google push implementation between android and php**

http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

Comment: I think the second approach is what I understand. But I don't know how to implement. Do you have any links that I may use or study in order to came up with the solution? Thanks in advance.